# Overriding MacVim's default filetype.vim when assigning filetypes

Tags: vim, macvim, file-type, janus

In the default `filetype.vim` that comes with [MacVim](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim), I have the following:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.erb,*.rhtml setf eruby
```

I installed [MacVim](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim) using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), and I've installed [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus). Following the instructions from [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus), I've created `~/.vimrc.local` to store my local customizations. I want to set the filetype for `*.html.erb` files to `html.eruby.eruby-rails`, so I added the following line to `~/.vimrc.local`.

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.html.erb setf html.eruby.eruby-rails
```

However, it appears that the filetype is still being selected by [MacVim](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim)'s default `filetype.vim` instead of picking up my change in `~/.vimrc.local`.

What do I need to do differently, so as to have [MacVim](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim) properly designate `*.html.erb` files as filetype `html.eruby.eruby-rails` without modifying the default `filetype.vim`?

Answer (score 8):

Change `setf` in your autocmd to `set ft=`.  If you take a look at `:help setf` it says it will not set the filetype if it has already been set elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I tried the following and it seems to work:

```
autocmd FileType eruby set ft=html.eruby.eruby-rails
```

However, if I understand correctly, this is changing all files that the default `filetype.vim` designates as `eruby` to a filetype of `html.eruby.eruby-rails`.